# Overflow in C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, overflow

What does C++ do with overflow?
What does Java do with overflow?

When C++ has a overflow error, i think it goes to the smallest possible number and adds from there, but I'm not exactly sure. I don't know how java handles this problem?

Comment: Overflow in C++ is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Let's add Perl in the mix too!

Comment: how does C++ handle the undefined behavior?

Comment: @cnicutar, I've never known that, but it seems that's correct. Thanks for pointing it out. Anyway, undefined behaviour is **undefined**. C++ doesn't handle it.

Comment: Integer overflow? Buffer overflow? If it's integers are you thinking signed or unsigned?

Comment: Don't see how it vague (if it is then very simple to make it explicit). Don't see it as incomplete (very explicit question). Do not see it as overly broad (The current two answers together cover the whole answer). It is not rhetorical (both answers quote from the standard). It can (and has) been reasonably answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In n3242 of the C++ standard

### 5 Expressions [expr]

#### Paragraph 5.4:

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, **the behavior is undefined**. [ Note: most existing implementations of C++ ignore integer overflows. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating point exceptions vary among machines, and is usually adjustable by a library function. —end note ]"

From OP

> When C++ has a overflow error, i think it goes to the smallest possible number and adds from there

No. It just seems like that sometimes.

Comment: That doesn't apply if it's unsigned: *"Unsigned integers, declared unsigned, shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo 2^n where n is the number
of bits in the value representation of that particular size of integer."* - n3290 § 3.9.1. This is clarified in footnote 46 *"This implies that unsigned arithmetic does not overflow because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting
unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the
resulting unsigned integer type."*

Comment: When it says it ignores integer overflows what does that exactly mean?

Comment: @user1251302: it means it pretends that integers can never overflow, and never checks to see if they overflowed or not.  Checking would slow the program down.

Comment: So it that why it switches from a positive number to a negative number?

Comment: @user1251302 - some implementations might choose to just kill the program. Or silently break everything. Or anything they like because it's *undefined*. Quite a lot of implementations chose to let it just pass through and do what the underlying hardware does, because that's fast and free.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie - are you serious? This is a C++ forum, ask Java questions at Java forum.

Comment: @awoodland - the question was about overflow, and as you noticed the standard guarantees that "unsigned arithmetic does not overflow"

Comment: What would the advantages and disadvantages if a computer language always threw an exception when overflow occurred

Comment: I'm assuming the disadvantage of this is that you if you have a integer you have certain boundaries that you have to keep in mind.

Comment: @GeneBushuyev "this is a c++ forum"?????

Answer (score 0):

As far as integer addition in java is concerned, overflow behaviour is defined by [JLS #15.18.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2):

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? This might be partial as it does not cover C++ but I don't think it deserves a downvote.